# How to change biztalk custom component (disassembler) tool box icon ?

Tags: biztalk

While creating Biztalk custom component (Disassembler) I was able to change icon into PipeLine editor, however I into Toolbox component  icon still default .

How can I change component Icon into toolbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the Icon through the Toolbox, it comes from the component Assembly.

If you used the Pipeline Component Wizard, the icon is stored in the Resource file as an Image.

Just add you own Image file (it has to be of certain diminsion) and change the Icon method to point to you new Image.